# Angular-UI Datepicker - Creating a Template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm new to AngularJS.  I am using this library:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

With it, I can show a datepicker using:

```
      <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation(); opened = true;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
```

I don't want to have to repeat this code everytime I have a datepicker.  Is there a way I can do something like:

And from that it just inserts the "template" code above?

-OR-

Is there a way or me to not have to add the ng-click attribute code to the button (have it globally set somehwere)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directive, that is *exactly* what it is meant for, avoid repeating boilerplate markup - as well as having imperative code that interacts with the dom in a clean separated environment. In fact, the datepicker is a directive itself. This is a nice tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

Comment: Awesome.  Worked great.

Comment: @user472292: Glad to hear!